# Network requests for stylesheet do get made, but aren't applied to HTML

Tags: html, css

[image: Initial situation]

This is the initial situation (a screenshot from Firefox' developer tools). There's a `<link rel="stylesheet">` in the header. Note how there aren't any styles applied to the `<body>` element (lower viewport). As you can see in the second picture, the web request to this stylesheet does in fact get made:

[image: Web request to stylesheet]

If I go to the `Style Editor` tab in Firefox' developer tools and add an extra character (in this case a newline between the `import` and the `body`), this causes Firefox to update the stylesheet and when that happens the styles do get applied to my webpage.

[image: Style editor tab in Firefox]
[image: Updated element inspector with applied styles]

How can I make sure my styles get applied on page load?

EDIT: I should mention that I didn't have these problems while testing my app using `create-react-server`'s development server or while using `python3 -m http.server` as web server. It only happens when I use nginx as a server, though I can't imagine what difference the server might make as all web servers return exactly the same static content.

Comment: Does this only happen in Firefox, or other browsers too?

Comment: This happens on Firefox Nightly, the latest chromium build and on iOS 13's Safari as far as I tested.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that my web server was sending a MIME-type of `text/plain` instead of `text/css`. I solved this in nginx by adding `include mime.types;` to the `html` element in `nginx.conf` and creating a `mime.types` file with the following content:

```
types {
  text/html                             html htm shtml;
  text/css                              css;
  text/javascript                       js;
}
```

It seems that this is a common issue with people using docker's `nginx:latest` image.